# CMS for Web directory

Tags: php, cms

[Web directories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_directory) have been disused several years ago and all the software I knew (such as eSyndiCat) did not seem very up to date.

Does anyone know if there are modern CMSs (in Php) to create web directories?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/), a modern CMS, and written in PHP. It can be used to build virtually any kind of websites, so for sure also for "web directories".

These days there are typically 3 releases of it being used:

- Drupal 7, very mature, and zillions of contributed modules (plugins to add specific facilities to a site), release around 2011.
- Drupal 8, pretty new, first beta release dates from late 2014. Major new facilities includes in its core version, but still missing lots of contributed modules (which haven't been upgraded from Drupal 7 yet).